# ¿Cómo utilizar inyección de dependencias en TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inyeccion-de-dependencias

Soy relativamente nuevo en TypeScript y pues me gustaría implementar inyección de dependencias en mi proyecto sin usar módulos. La cuestión es que soy alguien que tiene más experiencia en lenguajes que son más orientados a objetos como C# o Java.

Busqué en internet sobre cómo hacer esto pero lo único que obtuve es usar módulos, algo que no quiero usar aún sin primero intentarlo.

Ésta es mi clase base:

```
class Motor {
Acelerar(): void {
}
GetRevoluciones(): number {
let currentRPM: number = 0;
return currentRPM;
 }
}
export {Motor};
```

La clase que usa a `Motor`:

```
import { Motor } from "./1";
class Vehiculo {
private m: Motor;
public Vehiculo(motorVehiculo: Motor) {
    this.m = motorVehiculo;
}
public GetRevolucionesMotor(): number {
if (this.m != null) {
    return this.m.GetRevoluciones();
}
else {
    return -1;
}
}
}
export { Vehiculo };
```

La interface y el tipo de motor:

```
interface IMotor {
Acelerar(): void;
GetRevoluciones(): number;
 }
class MotorGasoline implements IMotor {
private DoAdmission() { }
private DoCompression() { }
private DoExplosion() { }
private DoEscape() { }
  Acelerar() {
   this.DoAdmission();
   this.DoCompression();
   this.DoExplosion();
   this.DoEscape();
 }
 GetRevoluciones() {
    let currentRPM: number = 0;
    return currentRPM;
  }
}
class MotorDiesel implements IMotor {
  Acelerar() {
   this.DoAdmission();
   this.DoCompression();
   this.DoCombustion();
   this.DoEscape();
}
GetRevoluciones() {
  let currentRPM: number = 0;
  return currentRPM;
}
 DoAdmission() { }
 DoCompression() { }
 DoCombustion() { }
 DoEscape() { }
 }
```

Y aquí es donde el error aparece:

```
 import { Vehiculo } from "./2";
 enum TypeMotor {
   MOTOR_GASOLINE = 0,
   MOTOR_DIESEL = 1
 }
 class VehiculoFactory {
 public static VehiculoCreate(tipo: TypeMotor) {
  let v: Vehiculo = null;
   switch (tipo) {
      case TypeMotor.MOTOR_DIESEL:
          v = new Vehiculo(new MotorDiesel()); break;
      case TypeMotor.MOTOR_GASOLINE:
          v = new Vehiculo(new MotorGasoline()); break;
      default: break;
  }
  return v;
  }
 }
```

He oído que se puede hacer en JavaScript así que he intentado implementarlo con TypeScript. Por el momento no estoy interesado en usar ningún módulo; sólo quiero implementarlo correctamente sin depender de ellos.

***Actualizado***

Me olvidé de poner el error. IntelliSense me muestra un error de este tipo:

> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Comment: Dices que aparece el error, pero no lo colocas en la pregunta, te recomiendo editarla, y poner el error, así seria mas fácil saber.

Comment: ya lo puse. intellisense me lo muestra, y x ende no puedo continuar

Answer (score 2):

> La cuestión es que soy alguien que tiene más experiencia en lenguajes que son **más orientados a objetos** como C# o Java.

JavaScript es orientado a objetos también, pero no de la forma tradicional que implementan C# y Java; JavaScript implementa un estilo de [orientación a objetos protipado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_basada_en_prototipos).

Lo que estás hanciendo se llama inversión de control (IoC) y es una técnica que consiste en **inyectar las dependencias desde fuera** de la clase. El modo que usa en Java por ejemplo, es por medio de un contenedor de dependencias que se resuelven en tiempo de ejecución por medio de calificadores, por ejemplo: `@Diesel`, `@Gasoline` para que no haya ambiguedad al inyectarlas.

Tu problema es que defines en el constructor que la clase `Vehiculo` **acepta una instancia de tipo** `Motor`, pero lo que estás pasando es una implementación de `IMotor`. Lo que debes hacer es cambiar la firma del constructor de `Vehiculo` para que acepte cualquier implementación de `IMotor`:

```
public Vehiculo(motorVehiculo: IMotor) {
    this.m = motorVehiculo;
}
```

De esta manera podrás pasar instancias de `MotorDiesel` y `MotorGasoline`.

---

**Cómo funciona el tipado estático en JavaScript/Typescript**

El tipado estático en estos lenguajes funciona similar a C# y Java. El tiempo de ejecución se evalúa si la instacia que se ha pasado es del tipo definido:

1. Instancia recibida en el constructor.
2. Evaluación de tipos.
3. ¿Es del tipo especificado?

   - Sí: continuar.
   - No: lanzar error.

En el paso dos se hace una especie de `typeof` para saber si el parámetro en realidad cumple los requisitos de la firma del método, de esta manera, Typescript puede "saber" si se ha cumplido la firma o no.

Ten en cuenta que Typescript es casi una implementación básica de C# para el lado cliente, y por ende, se trata de emular su comportamiento. Si sabes como funciona C#, entonces sabrás como funciona Typescript con mayor facilidad.

Comment: no me sirvio de esa manera, use un constructor usando la palabra reservada "constructor" y ya no tengo problemas

Comment: @AxlMrcer Puede haberte servido; pero estás usando mal la POO. Te recomiendo darle una repasada y estudiar los conceptos de inyección de dependencias e inversión de control.